# Bypass confirmation prompt for pip uninstall

Tags: python, django, module, pip, easy-install

I'm trying to uninstall all django packages in my superuser environment to ensure that all my webapp dependencies are installed to my virtualenv.

```
sudo su
sudo pip freeze | grep -E '^django-' | xargs pip -q uninstall
```

But pip wants to confirm every package uninstall, and there doesn't seem to be a `-y` option for pip. Is there a better way to uninstall a batch of python modules? Is `rm -rf .../site-packages/` a proper way to go? Is there an easy_install alternative?

Alternatively, would it be better to force pip to install all dependencies to the virtualenv rather than relying on the system python modules to meet those dependencies, e.g. `pip --upgrade install`, but forcing even **equally old** versions to be installed to override any system modules. I tried activating my virtualenv and then `pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt` and that does seem to install the dependencies, even those existing in my system path, but I can't be sure if that's because my system modules were old. And `man pip` doesn't seem to guarantee this behavior (i.e. installing the **same** version of a package that already exists in the system site-packages).

Answer (score 360, accepted):

starting with pip version 7.1.2 you can run `pip uninstall -y <python package(s)>`

```
pip uninstall -y package1 package2 package3
```

or from file

```
pip uninstall -y -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: bro, your are a true hero

Answer (score 72):

Pip does NOT include a --yes option (as of pip version 1.3.1).

**WORKAROUND:  pipe yes to it!**

```
$ sudo ls  # enter pw so not prompted again
$ /usr/bin/yes | sudo pip uninstall pymongo
```

Comment: ahh, how simple. thanks for the unix program reminder. `yes` is so useful.

Comment: but I don't think this would this work (too timid to try it on my system today). `yes | sudo pip freeze | grep -E '^django-' | xargs pip -q uninstall` because the `yes`es would get gobbled by the `pip freeze` not the `xargs` argument/command, `pip uninstall`.

Comment: `pip freeze > all_to_uninstall.txt`
`yes | pip uninstall -r all_to_uninstall.txt`

Comment: (for hobs 's issue above there's   [bash - How can I pipe yes to a program started by xargs? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57223133/how-can-i-pipe-yes-to-a-program-started-by-xargs) )

Answer (score 9):

If you want to uninstall every package from `requirements.txt`,

```
pip uninstall -y -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

on [www.saturncloud.io](https://www.saturncloud.io), Jupiter notebooks one can use like this:

```
!yes | pip uninstall tensorflow
!yes | pip uninstall gast
!yes | pip uninstall tensorflow-probability
```

Comment: what command to give for no?
Because !no | pip uninstall package_name does not seem to work

Comment: this was in 2021. I don't use saturncliud.io anymore....

Comment: I wanted to ask in jupyter notebook. No problem. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

> Alternatively, would it be better to force pip to install all dependencies to the virtualenv rather than relying on the system python modules to meet those dependencies,

Yes. Don't mess too much with the inbuilt system installed packages. Many of the system packages, particularly in OS X (even the debian and the derived varieties) depend too much on them.

> pip --upgrade install, but forcing even equally old versions to be installed to override any system modules.

It should not be a big deal if there are a few more packages installed within the venv that are already there in the system package, particularly if they are of different version. Thats the whole point of virtualenv.

> I tried activating my virtualenv and then pip install --upgrade -r requirements.txt and that does seem to install the dependencies, even those existing in my system path, but I can't be sure if that's because my system modules were old. And man pip doesn't seem to guarantee this behavior (i.e. installing the same version of a package that already exists in the system site-packages).

No, it doesn't install the packages already there in the main installation unless you have used the `--no-site-packages` flag to create it, or the required and present versions are different..

Answer (score 0):

Lakshman Prasad was right, `pip --upgrade` and/or `virtualenv --no-site-packages` is the way to go. Uninstalling the system-wide python modules is bad.

The `--upgrade` option to pip does install required modules in the virtual env, even if they already exist in the system environment, and even if the required version or latest available version is the same as the system version.

```
pip install --upgrade
```

And, using the --no-site-packages option when creating the virtual environment ensures that missing dependencies can't possibly be masked by the presence of missing modules in the system path. This helps expose problems during migration of a module from one package to another, e.g. pinax.apps.groups -> django-groups, especially when the problem is with load templatetags statements in django which search all available modules for templatetags directories and the tag definitions within.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -U xxxx
```

can bypass confirm

Comment: Please try to write full an meaningful sentences and edit code parts.

Comment: The -U is a force upgrade option not an uninstall