# Jupyter Notebook doesn't Uninstall package with pip

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I tried to remove a package with `pip` in a Jupyter notebook but it never finishes and I have to eventually restart the kernel without it uninstalling. I tried:

```py
!python -m pip uninstall pyserial
```

I found out why it hangs up. When running it from the command line, it asks whether I want to uninstall with a `yes`/`no` required.

```
Uninstalling pyserial-3.4:
  Would remove:
    c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyserial-3.4.dist-info\*
    c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\serial\*
    c:\Anaconda3\scripts\miniterm.py
Proceed (y/n)?
```

Perhaps the confirmation is a new feature of pip? It doesn't seem to be a problem in [How to uninstall a package installed with pip install --user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412974/how-to-uninstall-a-package-installed-with-pip-install-user). Is there a way to insert a `yes` response from the Jupyter notebook to not block future cells from running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bypass Confirmation Prompt for pip uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189199/bypass-confirmation-prompt-for-pip-uninstall)

Comment: Yes, that answer is close. That question wasn't about the Jupyter notebook appearing to freeze up. I didn't ever get to the `yes`/`no` confirmation so I didn't know what to search to overcome the problem. It may be worthwhile leaving this question if others encounter the same problem in an IPython notebook.

Comment: Thanks! This helped

Answer (score 28):

Try adding `--yes` to automatically answer the `yes`/`no` question.

```py
!python -m pip uninstall pyserial --yes
```

This uninstalls the package `pyserial`. You can use the `--yes` from the command line or in a Jupyter notebook cell.

```
Uninstalling pyserial-3.4:
  Successfully uninstalled pyserial-3.4
```

Comment: also the syntax `!python -m pip uninstall -y pyserial` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Jupyter notebook but Jupyter lab has a terminal environment that you can access from the Jupyter environment. I made  the switch some months back and it was worth it.

Comment: Jupyter notebook also has it, on terminals tab.