# Force pip uninstalll

Tags: pip

When I run `pip uninstall XXX` I got

```
Uninstalling XXX : whould remove ...
process(y/n)
```

How to automatically confirm it , something like  `pip uninstall -f XXX`

Comment: you can use `pip uninstall -y package` see: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189199/bypass-confirmation-prompt-for-pip-uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189199/bypass-confirmation-prompt-for-pip-uninstall)

Comment: You could find usage with `pip help uninstall`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+uninstall

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -y or --yes flags.  See the [official documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/).